# Variable Access 2007 Form Query Using Checkboxes?

Tags: sql, forms, checkbox, ms-access-2007

I'm new to Access and VBA but am familiar with SQL. I created an Access 2007 Table that has Yes/No checkboxes such as:

SentInvite
ReSetnInvite
RespondedYes
RespondedNo

And am trying to make a form (again in Access 2007) that would let me do queries against any checkbox combination.

So far I can do a query from the form for any ONE checkedbox such as SentInvite using:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Party  
Where forms!Invites!chxSent = True
```

But I cannot get it to allow me to do multiple checkboxes in a form query such as SentInvite, ReSentInvite, RespondedYes:

```
SELECT *
FROM Party
WHERE (forms!Invites!chxSent = True AND  
forms!Invites!chxReSent = True AND  
forms!Invites!chxYes = True)
```

I have to write out a SQL query each time.

How do I make it so depending on which checkboxes in the QueryForm I use the returned columns match?

I want to be able to check:

SentInvite
ReSetnInvite

and then click 'Search' and get back just those and then if I go back to my form and check:

ReSetnInvite
RespondedYes

and click 'Search' get back those results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have mixed the values from the form into your query instead of using the values from your form to provide values for (filtering) your query results.  Try to think of the values on your form as ordinary SQL variables (minus the @ symbol).  Try this query instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM Party
WHERE Party.SentInvite = forms!Invites!chxSent AND  
    Party.ReSent = forms!Invites!chxReSent AND  
    Party.RespondedYes = forms!Invites!chxYes
```